# how GetComponentInChildren in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, assign

I have a problem:

How to assign `[]` status to `rend[]`

```
public GameObject[] Obj;
private bool[] Status;
private MeshRenderer[] rend;

private void Start () 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Obj.Length; i++)
    {
        rend[i] = GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
        Status[i] = rend[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to determine the status - true or false - of MeshRenderer instance?

Comment: What do you mean by `[]` status? Array status? I've never heard of `[]` status

Comment: Do you mean if the MeshRenderer is `enabled`?

Answer (score 0):

Accorting to [Object.bool](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) you can try this way:

```
public GameObject[] Obj ;
private bool[] Status;
private MeshRenderer[] rend;

void Start () {
    for (int i = 0; i < Obj.Length; i++)
    {
        rend[i] = Obj[i].GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
        Status[i] = rend[i] != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you'll end up with an array filled with `true`s because none of them will be null. :P

Comment: So what do you mean under status of `MeshRenferer` object?

Comment: The question is quite unclear to be fair but you are making the same mistake using `GetComponentInChildren` allways on the object this script is attached to ... you never use the objects from `Obj` what I guess is what the OP wanted

Comment: @Draco18s not necessarily: If the object simply had no `MeshRenderer` component under its hierarchy than `rend[i]` would be `null`

Comment: See [my asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52147714/7111561): you still can not simply assign a value to an array using `array[i]=` if the array is never initialized using `array = new <Type>[<Size>]`

Comment: @derHugo You are correct, I thought I was looking at `GetComponentsInChildren` which returns an array (it might be empty, but it is non-null!)

Comment: thank you for answering my question, but I already know the problem. Status[i] = Obj[i].GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().enabled;

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear so I can just guess what you are trying to archieve:

I'ld say you want to find the first `MeshRenderer` under your GameObjects in `Obj` and get an array `Status` saying whether they are enabled or not.

1. You are currently allways searching for `MeshRenderer` in the GameObject this script is attached to instead of looking in the `Obj` GameObjects. You have to get it using

   ```
   Obj[i].GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
   ```
2. you probably don't initailize your arrays -> you cannot just assign values using `Status[i] =` and `rend[i] =` if the arrays were never initialized using `new`. You can either do that in start once you have the size of `Obj`

   ```
   public GameObject[] Obj;
   private bool[] Status;
   private MeshRenderer[] rend;

   private void start()
   {
       Status = new bool[Obj.Length];
       rend = new MeshRenderer[Obj.Length];
       // ...
   }
   ```

   but I would prefer using a `List<bool>` and `List<MeshRenderer>` instead so you can simply add and remove values later (while an array has a fixed length).
3. Finally I guess you want to know whether the component `MeshRenderer` is enabled so you can assign `rend[i].enabled`

**all together**
something like

```
public GameObject[] Obj ;
// Using List here you can already initialize it here 
// which would be possible using an array
private List<bool> Status = new List<bool>();
private List<MeshRenderer> rend = new List<MeshRenderer>();

private void Start(){
    for (int i = 0; i < Obj.Length; i++)
    {
        rend.Add(Obj[i].GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>());
        bool existsAndEnabled = rend[i] != null && rend[i].enabled;
        Status.Add(existsAndEnabled); 
    }
}
```

Note that it is still possible that for one of the GameObjects in `Obj` there is no `MeshRenderer` found so I say `Status` shall also be `false` if there was none.

Comment: Glad to help! If it solved your problem feel free to accept the answer as solution so other people can see your question is solved already.